# Android app showing 2 icon in device while testing

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio

I'm new to android and Developing very basic App. I have completed my development but when ever I debug my app in device. It shows 2 icon. I'm facing this problem after implementing Splash Screen in my app. Please suggest me how to overcome. My manifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/icc"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity
        android:name=".SplashScreen"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".Login_page">
           <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

Comment: what do you mean by two icons..?

Comment: Sorry for ambiguity. 2 application icon to launch.

Comment: there should be only one intent filter with categroy launcher

Comment: Thank you @VivekMishra. As per suggestion I removed 1 category from .login_page and Its working fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your manifest file -

```
<intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
```

This piece of code means which activity will first start when you launch the app. But you have put this code in both of your activities hence Android provides a separate launcher for both the activities and you see two icons.

So remove the above code from one of the activities. Just let it remain in the Activity you want to start first when your app launches.

Comment: Or you can just remove the line:     <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"

Answer (score 1):

TO have a icon on the launcher screen you need action of the activity to be action_main and category to be launcher and your both activity qualifies the criteria for this. 
You should change your login_activity category to default or simply remove the category. 
You can start your login activity from splash activity.
I hope it helps you.

Comment: Thank you ankit for your response. I tried that but after splash screen my App is geting unfortunately stopped.

Comment: Thank you so much Ankit. your suggestion is Working I just removed <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" /> from .login_page and its working.